# In Drupal, I want to have two (or more) views_embed_view on a page

Tags: php, drupal

I have a view that will display the four most recent blog posts from a blog using `views_embed_view` and an argument. I've also specified the theme info. In a block I am using:

```
print views_embed_view('NAME', 'DISPLAY', 'ARG');
```

In my case, using ('blog_view', 'default', 'Blog 1'). I would like to embed this a second time, replacing Blog 1 with Blog 2.

Blog 1 displays perfectly (first node has title and description, next three are a list of the node titles). When I display Blog 2, all it does is display the title linking to the node (for all four, not using any styling defined in the template file).

Can I display two views using views_embed_view? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to create two separate block views and place those blocks in the page itself.